# Are the elements of $R=\mathbb{Q}[x]/\left<(x-1)^3\right>$ just constants?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

My understanding of the ring are that you treat the ideal as doing (x-1)^3=0 and therefore substituting 1 for x in every element, but it doesn’t make sense in the problem that I’m doing.

Comment: It is a quotient ring, so you can think of it as taking polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and 'factoring out' by $(x-1)^3$ (precisely, the ideal generated by $(x-1)^3$).

Comment: Thinking of it in the same way as with subgroups such as $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, the elements are of the form $x + 5n$, where we take out 'as many copies' of $5$ as possible to get the coset rep.

Answer (score 1):

No, in this ring the polynomial $(x-1)^3$ is like $0$, in other words,
$$
0 = (x-1)^3 = x^3-3x^2+3x-1 \iff x^3 = 3x^2-3x+1
$$

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding of the ring are that you treat the ideal as doing $(x-1)^3=0$ and therefore substituting $1$ for $x$ in every element, but it doesn’t make sense in the problem that I’m doing.

Your understanding here is wrong. Here the equality $(x-1)^3=0$ is not an equality for a real number $x$, but an equality of *polynomials*, formal expressions in terms of the indeterminate $x$. So from $(x-1)^3=0$ you cannot conclude that $(x-1)=0$ and hence $x=1$; all you can conclude is that $x^3-3x^2+3x-1=0$, in other words that $x^3-3x^2+3x-1$ is considered "the same as" the $0$ polynomial in this ring.